# How can I stop the running animation from Jquery when the window is resized?

Tags: jquery, css, responsive

I am using Jquery for CSS animation. I am trying to make my website responsive and I want to stop some animations that I did with Jquery when the window is smaller

Comment: Listen to the resize event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize

Comment: When it comes to non dynamic changes to jQuery when a window is resized I find that it is often best to only apply the changes when the window stops resizing. Take a look at this CSS Tricks article https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/done-resizing-event/. Try and achieve what you want using that example and if you have any issues, create a new question with an example of your code.

Answer (score 1):

I found a simpler solution (for these who are interested), here what I did

1. I stocked the window width  in a variable

```js
var showidth = $(window).width()
```

2. I added a condition that allow me to run all my animation functions only when the window is bigger than 864px for example (phone width)

`if (showidth > 864){    //my CSS animation code    }`

And it worked. Of course we can find lot of other solutions, If I was using Jquery animation (animate function) for example, I could simply use the .stop() method on the animations on window.resize().

Here is a screenshot of my code

[JqueryCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyEmu.png)